# Using clickable links in DialogFlow

Tags: dialogflow-es

Is possible to use hyperlinks in the middle of some text with DialogFLow?

Currently the best I can get is to use DialogFlow Messenger with an extra response of type Custom Payload and add there a richContent response of type "info" with the link.

But I want to add the link as a normal "< a href >" element, is that possible somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Did you already try to send raw URL in your message?

It will automatically turn the URL into a link in almost all chat application.

I already try in Telegram, Facebook Messenger, Line Messenger, etc.

Comment: Customer could also make use of rich responses in order to enhance user interaction: https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/df-asdk/rich-responses